# How to create a reference library of c# class libraries and projects

Tags: c#, libraries, repository

We have a large LOB application that does fairly complex transaction processing of various types. All our code is written in C# and consists of class libraries, console apps, windows forms apps and web applications. The class libraries contain the core functionality and business logic  and is reused in the application solutions. We have a folder of pre-compiled DLL's of all our class libraries that are referenced by other projects. Sometimes, instead of referencing the pre-complied DLL's, we might need to include the library's full project into the solution we are working on. This makes debugging and unit testing easier typically.

Over years, this library of Visual Studio projects and solutions and DLL's has grown to the point that we typically do not know all the reference of a particular class library, i.e. we can't tell in which of the solutions any given class library (or any reusable project for that matter) is being included or referenced.

How would I go about creating a easy-to-use lookup-reference of sorts of all our source code to make it easier to find library references across all projects and solutions?

Comment: Resharper does something like this, though your problem sounds more like a training one.

Comment: What is the -1 for? Is this not a valid programming question?

Comment: We don't provide product recommendations of any kind here.  I only mentioned Resharper because we use it in our shop.  Good organization and discipline is better than any tool, though.

Comment: If I need to find out which of our solutions references a specific lib, I often use the global search feature of a text editor like Notepad++: find "XYZ.csproj" in all files of type "*.sln". below our dev root folder.

Comment: Tools, or "products", are a big part of programming so I see no problem in helping a fellow developer out in that regard. IMHO. Anyway, we have ReSharper and I'll do some reading up on it abilities as I've only started using it recently. Is that the training you are referring to, @RobertHarvey ?

Comment: Hard to say.  If you're one of those shops that regularly throws a library at every problem you encounter, you might simply have too many references.  There's a non-trivial cost associated with this practice.

Comment: This site's scope is not about "helping fellow developers" in arbitrary ways. In fact, there is currently a renaming process in place, the site will probably become renamed to "Software Engineering Stack Exchange".. If you have questions about specific development tools, Stackoverflow is much better suited (but please do not crosspost).

Comment: Stack Overflow doesn't make product recommendations either.

Comment: @RobertHarvey: no, but on Stackoverflow he could ask how to solve his problem using Visual Studio. Or better just look into this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38451101/in-visual-studio-how-do-you-find-other-projects-referencing-a-single-project-in question first, to avoid his question to be closed as a dupe.

Comment: And don't you use software tools and products for software engineering...? Amusing... lol ...even notepad is a "product" ...

Comment: @Neville: You're missing the point.  On Stack Exchange, we have a sharp focus on a specific topic.  Here, that topic is *software design,* not tools.  Yes, we use tools.  It doesn't matter.

Comment: @RobertHarvey I hear you and get the point. Tools per say do not define software design but are used to enable it. Therefore, I thought someone here would have an idea on how to reverse-engineer (for lack of a better phrase) an existing software design. I walked in here 7 months ago and was horrified when I discovered all the class libraries and references, but my job is not to criticize, it is to improve and help build but also maintain what is already in place. If I can help them understand the beast built over 8+ years by various devs that have come and gone, then that is a good thing.

Comment: If you simply rephrased your question to something like "how might I go about doing _this specific thing_" instead of "what products can I use to do this thing" then your question wouldn't be asking for a product recommendation.

Comment: Would the answer be any different then? Honestly?

Comment: It might incorporate techniques that are already at your disposal.  For this site, it would still have to be about *software design,* though, since that's the topic area for this site.

Comment: Software metrics including Cyclomatic Complexity are included out of the box in Visual Studio Professional and above I believe. If you don't have that version, do a search on that term (Cyclomatic Complexity) and you'll find other tools like it.

Comment: Yeah, the answer might be to use a technique that isn't "install and run this tool". But, you'd never know if you ask for a tool. And this site isn't for tooling recommendations, for various very good reasons.

Comment: "This makes debugging and unit testing easier typically." How so?

Comment: When debugging in Visual Studio, you can not step into code referenced by DLL. One needs to reference that DLL's project, i.e. source code, in the existing project.

Comment: @Neville it won't help you right now, but I recommend that you start generating the *.pdb symbol files and set yourself up a server so that you can better debug your libraries without this nonsense of adding a copy of the code to the project.

Comment: @RubberDuck I agree 100% and this is a big part of what I'm trying to achieve ultimately. This is an old team, stuck in their ways, that I joined recently. I need to show them how bad this really is.